Global sections of a line bundle associated to a non-effective divisor
The following is a proof of the index theorem for divisors given in pp.472-473 of Griffiths-Harris.
Let $M$ be a projective surface, and $E$ a positive divisor, meaning that the Chern class of the associated line bundle can be represented by a positive $(1,1)$-form. Suppose $D$ is a divisor on $M$ with $D\cdot E=0$ and $D\cdot D=d>0$. Since $E\cdot D'>0$ for any effective $D'$, $mD$ cannot be effective for all nonzero $m$. By Riemann-Roch, $$ h^0(mD)-h^1(mD)+h^2(mD)=\frac{1}{2}m^2d-\frac{m}{2}KD+\chi(\mathcal{O}_M)$$
so $$h^0(K-mD)=h^2(mD)\geq \frac{1}{2}m^2d-\frac{m}{2}KD+\chi(\mathcal{O}_M) .$$
Where did the term $h^0(mD)$ go? Since $|mD|$ is the projectivization of $H^0(mD)$, I see that $h^0(mD)=0$ if and only if $|mD|=\emptyset$. But does $|mD|=\emptyset$ follow from non-effectiveness of $mD$?
Does the condition $mD$ noneffective imply that its associated line bundle has no global sections? I only see that for a fixed $m$, either $h^0(mD)=0$ or $h^0(-mD)=0$.

$h^0(D) = 0$ if and only if $D$ is not equivalent to an effective divisor. Since intersection pairing depends only on equivalence class of a divisor, clearly $mD$ not only cannot be effective, but also cannot be equivalent to an effective divisor, so the proof works. It is possible (I don't remember to be honest) that Griffiths and Harris define effective divisors as all divisors that are equivalent to effective (i.e. a sum of subvarieties of codimension $1$ with nonnegative coefficients). In this case the statement is just true: if $D$ is not effective, then $h^0(D) = 0$.

@Matsmir Thanks a lot, I think  you can use your comment as an answer

PIcky point: Write $|mD|=\emptyset$, not $=0$.

@TedShifrin You're right, I've made an edit.
